# Sql Error - Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting following error when I submit a form:

```
Can't added a new post. Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'aid' at row 1
```

**Php Code:**

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO brt_articles VALUES( '', '$post_title', '$des', 
'$date', '$org_date')");    

    if($insert)
    {
        echo "<font color=green>Successfully added a new article.</font>";
        header("Refresh:3; url=allbrtarticle.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<font color=red>Can't added a new post</font>" . 
              mysql_error();
    }
```

In my Localhost It's ok. But in server why it's giving me a error message ?

Comment: what is the type of column `aid`?

Comment: change `aid` to `autoincrement` in database table will fix the issue.

Comment: Well, @Madan Sapkota, I'm checking it..

Comment: @Madan Sapkota It's already set to autoincrement.

Comment: @BabuAhmed, i posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aid` field does not accept `''` value as input.

The safest way is to specify column names as you are sending the query.

```
INSERT INTO brt_articles (title_field, description_field, date_field, org_date, fieldname) VALUES('$post_title', '$des', '$date', '$org_date');
```

If `aid` is a primary key, simply omit that field in your query

```
INSERT INTO brt_articles VALUES('$post_title', '$des', '$date', '$org_date')
```

Comment: Thanks @Starx Working with your first statement. But I already set aid column to primary key and autoincrement. So why your second statement is not working ?

Comment: And I upload it(my code) to another server BUT It's working fine!

Answer (score 2):

Probably that DB has differents settings than your local. [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables) mode might be turned on. 
Try `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` and `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;`.

Answer (score 0):

`aid` is a column that is an integer, and you're trying to insert `''` into it. `''` is not a number, so the insertion fails.

Perhaps there's a server setting to auto-convert the incorrect type, but you shouldn't rely on it (as you've just found out)

Answer (score 0):

This causes the error **aid**(INT) - which is included on you table columns(first column).

If its auto increment remove the ''.

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO brt_articles VALUES('$post_title', '$des', 
'$date', '$org_date')");
```

Regards

Comment: It's a autoincrement field.

Comment: you should not be adding a value if its auto increment field.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"INSERT INTO brt_articles VALUES('".$post_title."', '".$des."', '".$date."', '".$org_date."')"
```

Remove first `''` it's not needed as MySQL automatically add it if its `primary key` and `auto_increment`.

Answer (score 0):

your local db has the value of that column set to auto increment or has a default value.

on the server db, the table definition is not the same.

review and compare the table definitions and then make them consistent.

Comment: if he uploaded the local database tables to server, then your statement is not true.

Comment: thanks - now i see the nonexistent text where he says he uploaded the local database tables to the server